# exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, arduino-esp32

since the last update to Mac OS Monterey 12.3 I get the following error message when compiling my Arduino sketch:

```
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find out how to solve this problem.

I would be very grateful for ideas and suggestions.

Comment: You need to add Python path to `.zprofile`

Comment: If like me you end up here with this same problem, but on Debian-based Linux, this fixed it for me: sudo apt install python-is-python3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Problem

In MacOS 12.3 Apple removed python2.7 (`python`) from MacOS.

## Solution

What I did to solve this is link `python3` to `python`, I wouldn't recommend it because it's sus, I would recommend you wait until Arduino IDE fixes this issue in a later build. For the time being, you could try their Web IDE: [Arduino Editor](https://create.arduino.cc/editor/wonathanjellington/e2d252de-c3e1-4dbe-99db-8872db976124)

However, here are the instructions to link `python3` to `python`:

0. If you don't have `python3` installed, install it here in the link below:

   [Python Install Page](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
1. Find your path for the current version of `python3` you're using

   `which python3`

   it'll show up with something like this:
   `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`
2. Copy that and use it to run this command that links `python 3` to `python`. Replace the first file path with where your `python3` is.

   `ln -s -f INSERT_PATH_OF_PYTHON3 /usr/local/bin/python`

   for example:

   `ln -s -f /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: It's almost the end of 2023 and this issue exists on Apple Silicon.

Comment: I've done all this but I kept being told: "xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools".   But I've already installed the developer tools.

Comment: @RustyShackleford damn, it’s still an issue? I would’ve assumed Arduino IDE would have fixed this by now. Have you installed python3?

Comment: Python3 was already in Ventura - which came on the new machine where this became a problem for me (it was working fine on my old Intel/Monterey machine).

Comment: Making this softlink seemed to fix it:
 cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin; sudo ln -s python3 python

Comment: Glad it’s working!

Answer (score 16):

Four steps are needed:

1. Install python3 using i.e. Brew:

   ```
   brew install python
   ```

   python3 is in:

   ```
   /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
   ```
2. Link Python to python3:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python
   ```
3. Check if you can execute it from the terminal; i.e.,

   ```
   python --version
   ```

   Irrespective of whether you use `python --version` or `python3 --version`, it should show python 3 now.
4. Open terminal and execute:

   ```
   open /Applications/Arduino.app
   ```

It works in my case. It looks like when Arduino is executed from the GUI, it does not read the `$PATH` properly, so although python is linked to python3, it does not find it.